# Rails credentials returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 6.0.0rc2 app and I'm having trouble reading my credentials.

When I do `rails credentials:edit` I can add credentials and they're saving just fine.

```
aws:
  access_key_id: 123
  secret_access_key: 345
```

However, when I run a console and try reading the credentials I get the following:

```
Rails.application.credentials[:aws]
  => nil
```

or

```
Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

or

```
Rails.application.credentials[:aws][:access_key_id]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

No matter what I try my credentials always seem to be `nil`.

If I run `Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base` I get the correct result, so the file can be read just fine.

Comment: You mentioned that `Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base` works. What about `Rails.application.credentials[:secret_key_base]`? Maybe access by symbol is broken. Which version of ruby are you using? You might be able to do `Rails.application.credentials.aws.access_key_id`.

Comment: `Rails.application.credentials[:secret_key_base]` works fine. `Rails.application.credentials.aws.access_key_id` gives me the `undefined method` result like above. Ruby version is: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]

Comment: hmmm perhaps you have a hidden character somewhere in your file that is breaking things. I would delete everything in the file after `secret_key_base` and try retyping the `aws` portion of the file manually, without copying it.

Comment: I deleted everything and typed it out again by hand. Still having the same issue

Comment: For the record I'm having the exact same issue. I can get the secret_key_base but nothing else. Is it somehow a weird permissions error ?

Comment: Is this still unresolved? If so, check if you have a `config/credentials/` directory. If you do, and it has environment-specific credentials files, this may be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue too.  For me I restarting the Rails server fixed the problem.

Chances are the server either doesn't pick up the changes automatically, or that the server needs to be restarted whenever you create a new credentials.yml.enc file.

Comment: I think it's a rails codebase issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947
seems like all information required to boot the application needs to be provided, including credentials.

Comment: it is amazing how often i forget to simply restart the server. this fixed it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `dig`?

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Something like this might work:

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id)
```

Comment: Same story. Returns `nil`

Comment: what do you get if you run `bin/rails credentials:show` in your terminal?

Comment: That works in that I can see the whole contents of the file

Comment: There was a syntax error in my original answer, do you get better results now?

Comment: I already noticed that syntax error and removed the "." I'm afraid

Comment: Based on what you've posted I'm at a loss...it could be a bug with 6.0.0rc2 but that's just speculation.

Comment: I have the same issue with rails 5.2

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I had updated credentials file using sublime.
Even on restarting the server I was unable to make the changes.
I closed the terminal and then it started reflecting the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what was the hack in this but at first, I ran this command

```
EDITOR='gedit' rails credentials:edit
```

which will create the master.key and credentials.yml.enc files. After adding some values in credentials.yml.enc file I was unable to get values via

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:test_var)
```

so I ran the former command with a bit change

```
EDITOR='gedit' rails credentials:edit --environment development
```

The upper command will create development.key and development.yml.env in config/credentials/ folder. And now the **Rails.application.credentials.dig(:test_var)** is able to get value of test_var key although I have deleted the whole config/credentials/ folder.

I don't really know what was the hack here but this was the whole scenario which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) does not work, however, if you remove the ':aws, ' and use Rails.application.credentials.dig(:access_key_id), it will pull the value for the item in the secrets file named 'access_key_id:'.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself, and the way I was able to access the data was to make a helper method such as:

```
  def credentials
    Rails.application.credentials[:aws]&.with_indifferent_access
  end
```

Then using `credentials[:access_key_id]` I was able to access the inner keys. If I tried doing `Rails.application.credentials[:aws]` from the controller I was in, it did not work, but if I used the helper method it did. ‍♀️

Maybe this will help someone, or maybe this was just my luck. I banged my head on it for about 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, though I'm not sure if it's the same as yours. If your access_key has reserved characters in it, it will not be parsed properly. Even a character like "!", will cause problems. In the credentials.yml.enc file, wrap your values in quotes. When you access those values, use the dump method to escape the problematic characters. So in your case, `Rails.application.credentials[:aws][:access_key_id].dump`